# Cómo ver el logcat del emulador de Android?

Tags: android, android-studio, logcat

Quiero ver los procesos y porque se cierra la app que tengo en el emulador usando el logcat

Comment: Cual es el problema en realidad? no se ve en Android Studio el LogCat o no se despliega informaciòn, agrega màs informaciòn a tu pregunta por favor, revisar [ask] saludos

Comment: el logcat no despliega ninguna informacion usando el emulador, pero si uso mi telefono si

Comment: que marca es tu cel? activaste el modo debug?

Comment: Mi teléfono personal es un Xiaomi y funciona el logcat sin problemas, dónde no funciona es en el emulador de Android studio.